# Searching Recyclerview - scroll to top when search is empty

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement search functionality in my recyclerview using room and a viewmodel.

The functionality works just fine while searching. However if I empty the search string the recyclerview does not scroll to the top of the complete list.

Below the code:

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: MyRepository) :
    ViewModel() {
    private var nameFilter = MutableLiveData<String>("")

    val allPosts : LiveData<List<Post>> = Transformations.switchMap(nameFilter) { name ->
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            repository.getAllPosts()
        } else {
            repository.getPostByName(name)
        }
    }


    fun getPostByName(name: String) {
        nameFilter.postValue(name)
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val listAdapter = MyListAdapter()
        binding.RV.apply {
            adapter = listAdapter
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
            // Just for spacing
            addItemDecoration(RecyclerViewCustomItemDecorator(8, 8))
        }


        binding.searchRV.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
                viewModel.getPostByName(editable.toString())
            }

        })

        viewModel.allPosts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            listAdapter.submitList(it)
        }
    }
```

The Recyclerview adapter implements the diffUtil logic.

Hope anyone can help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In recycler view there is a property to scroll on top when user is bottom of scroll
**mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);**

SmoothScrollToPosition help in smoothly scroll on top you can also use **mRecyclerView.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)**

If we use scroll view then use

**scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);**.

Comment: I tried both your approches. However, **smoothScrollToPosition(0)** works it might take a long time and it looks ugly. The **scrollToPosition(0)** does not scroll to the very top